# difference between [-0-9] and [-0-9 ] pattern in awk command

Tags: awk

What is difference between the following commands:

```
awk '/[-0-9]/ {print $0}' data_file
```

and:

```
awk '/[-0-9 ]/ {print $0}' data_file
```

the second command differs by a space in `[-0-9]` pattern from the first command.

Can you explain what is role of the space in `[...]` in second commands?

Comment: This is more of a regexp question than an `awk` question.

Answer (score 2):

It indicates that your pattern can match any space character in input string:

```
$ echo " " | awk '/[-0-9]/ {print "match"}'
$ echo " " | awk '/[-0-9 ]/ {print "match"}'
match
```